# The method click() is undefined for the type MobileElement

Tags: java, appium-android

i am geeting this error on eclipse while i am running my appium code The method click() is undefined for the type MobileElement , whereas i have imported each and every method.

my code should runThe method click() is undefined for the type MobileElement problem should not appear when i want to run my code

Comment: Please show us the code

Comment: what version are you using? chances are, you have a dependency clash somewhere.

Comment: @fascynacja i have uploaded the code in comment

Comment: @Stultuske i am using the updated version before this the error was appearing of main.java lang no such method found & when copied & pated my code in new window again it's giving me an error of click() is undefined in MobileElement.

Comment: Pleae put the code in the body of  your question so we can all see it